# How can I save a Google Maps route offline?

Tags: google-maps

Just what the title says.

I've been looking everywhere and all I can find is how to save a particular map view, but not a route between two points.

Comment: How are you saving that map view? Are you using the new Google Maps?

Comment: ...and, to be clear, you're talking about the normal desktop web app and not, say, the Android app, right?

Comment: @AlE. I was thinking about the Android app, but I assumed if it was possible to do it on the desktop then it should be possible to view it on Android using a web browser.

Comment: That is not always the case at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems Google does not have a feature to "save a route offline". After finding this out I was actually surprised to hear it as well as you might be to. Google should definitely be adding a feature like this.

To try and help you out a little bit some suggestions for what you could do is:

1. ***print the map out ***(after you make your route)
2. ***screenshot the route and then go through the images***(when offline)

To sum it up, there is no such thing right now of saving routes offline, you can only save maps offline and I gave you some suggestions. Hope this helps:)

If you still need help here is a Google support link:

[Support.google.com/maps](https://support.google.com/maps/?hl=en)

This one is for Google maps mobile:

[Support.google.com/mobile/maps](https://support.google.com/gmm/?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually simple if you work from your desktop to your phone:

1. Create your route on the desktop app.
2. Share the route to your email (click on the phone) and select email.
3. Paste the route (a very long URL) in the body of the email.
4. If your email is synced go to the draft mail on your phone, click on the URL, which opens the route in Google Maps, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to no longer be possible.

Workaround: Print (within your browser).  Then print to pdf.  For example, if you install Foxit PDF Viewer, this will enable printing to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone but you can save offline routes on android by adding them to your home screen.

[image]

You can launch these routes without internet. you do need to have the required map downloaded.